# Several issues with 14.04.2 slow network, high samba cup usage

Tags: networking, printing, samba, vmware, zentyal

I have Ubuntu Trusty 14.04.2 installed with Zentyal and openchange.  It is running on  Vmware 5.1 with 8GB ram and 1 cpu with 4 cores.
I am having a huge problem with network traffic being very slow (taking about 2 hours to transfer 100M) and samba has high cpu usage any time anyone gets on the system.  It can run up as much as 100% and stay for a while.
I know ebox is part of the Zentyal package and I have seen posts where this package caused problems as well. 
Where would be a good place to start and what info can I provide to help with this issue?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.